# Java - Load content from IP instead of domain

Tags: java, android, http, url

This code works fine when I load content from the server but when i replace the server URL with IP-address i get IOException error.

Any ideas why?

```
String URLToFetch = "http://www.example.com";
final URL url = new URL(URLToFetch);
URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
c.setUseCaches(false);
c.setConnectTimeout(8000);
c.setReadTimeout(8000);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
if ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i("tag", "Result from HTTP: " + str.toString());
}
in.close();
```

I even used used this but it didn't work

```
final URL url = new URL("http", ServerIpAddress, 80, "/index.php");
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you replace the server URL with an IP address? The web doesn't work that way

Comment: I'm loading content from 10 parallell servers which don't have any domains connected to them.

Comment: 1/ You say you're getting an error. What is the error message? 2/ Have you verified the servers are working, using something other than your own program?

Comment: Yes servers are working fine. It's an IOException error. 
I even made sure the server allows cross origin.
I have even tried to load from my local machine on 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.230 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? "IOException error" does not give enough information to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the problem. The error says:
cleartext http traffic to (Servers IP) not permitted

Here's the problem:

> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

All I needed to do to solve this problem was to add this to my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: But... You said that  `http://www.example.com` worked fine. Impossible. That will not have worked either then.

Comment: Domains worked normally. Only ip-addresses failed to load.